# Disallowing additional properties in a Kubernetes CRD schema

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

Let's say I have the following CRD:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: examples.tomasaschan.com
spec:
  group: tomasaschan.com
  names:
    kind: Example
    listKind: Examples
    plural: examples
    singular: example
  scope: Namespaced
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          properties:
            spec:
              properties:
                foo:
                  type: string
              type: object
          type: object
```

A valid example object would look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: tomasaschan.com/v1
kind: Example
metadata:
  name: example1
spec:
  foo: bar
```

Now, because `foo` isn't required, if I misspell it this resource will still be accepted by the API server:

```yaml
apiVersion: tomasaschan.com/v1
kind: Example
metadata:
  name: example1
spec:
  boo: far
```

I would like to make it so that this raises a schema validation error.

In JSONSchema, I'd do that by setting `additionalProperties: false` on the `schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec` node, but that's not allowed structural CRD schemas (if I try, the API server responds with `Forbidden: additionalProperties and properties are mutual exclusive`).

[This old thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94593#issuecomment-688410004) recommends setting `spec.preserveUnknownFields: false` (on the CRD spec); in more recent Kubernetes versions this is instead accomplished by setting `x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: false` on each object node in the schema, but as far as I understand they are otherwise equivalent (modulo the scope they apply to). The effect of that would be the API server *dropping* the misspelled property, but still happily accepting the resulting config - I want it to return a `400` response with a validation error message that the property `boo` is unknown.

How do I best accomplish that?

Comment: specify required: [foo] to ensure that foo is required within the spec object.

Comment: @Gupta that's not an option in my case, because I want the foo property to be optional.

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes API server's validation mechanism is intended to be tolerant, ignoring unknown fields rather than rejecting them. The schema validation in Kubernetes is based on OpenAPI v3, which is designed to ignore additional properties by default. See https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/06/20/crd-structural-schema/

As you already stated corretly `x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields` will not cause an error. And also `additionalProperties`: false is not possible.

If you **really need to achieve this at all cost** you can accomplish this by creating a validating admission webhook that checks the resource for unknown properties and rejects the request if any are found. This would involve more complex logic and would need to be maintained separately from the CRD itself.
Therefore you need to decide on your own if this works for you.